# Visualizing a Protovis Network Layout on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, networking, dictionary, visualization, protovis

I currently have a bunch of dots drawn with Protovis on top of Google Maps using the API. It looks like this: http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/oakland.html

But I don't just want dots -- I want lines connecting the dots to show a network. I thought I could use the Protovis Network Layout (pv.Layout.Network) on Google Maps using the `nodes` and `links` properties and the pv.Dot and pv.Line classes. The nodes are showing up on my map, but not the links. Two other users have already asked similar questions on the Protovis discussion group, but nobody has answered. It seems like it should be simple.

My code is basically the same as the Oakland Crime-spotting example above, but I changed the "Render the visualization" part of the code to this:

```
p = new pv.Panel()
  .canvas(c)
  .left(-x.min)
  .top(-y.min);

var pn = p.add(pv.Layout.Network)
  .nodes(this.exampleNetwork.nodes)
  .links(this.exampleNetwork.links);

pn.link.add(pv.Line)

pn.node.add(pv.Dot)
   .left(function() pixels[this.index].x)
   .top(function() pixels[this.index].y)

p.render();
```

This is the part that adds the Network Layout to the visualization. Again, the nodes are working fine, but the links don't show up. I'd appreciate any help!

Update: Here's an example of a Force-Directed Layout in Protovis, which uses the Network Layout: http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/force.html. And yes, I know that Protovis is a bit obsolete.

Here's an example of what my data looks like:

```
var exampleNetwork = {
nodes:[
    {
      nodeName : "Example1",
      nodeValue : 100,
      group : 0,
      lat : 40.726446,
      lon : -74.007339
    },
    {
      nodeName : "Example2",
      nodeValue : 2048,
      group : 0,
      lat : 34.073137,
      lon : -118.248596
    }
 ],
  links:[
{source:0, target:1, value:5}
]
};
```

Comment: can you create a simpler version of the code? and/or set up a jsFiddle? This is very hard to inspect. As a sidemark, I think protovis has been made redundant by d3.js

Comment: I cannot think of a more fitting city than Oakland to illustrate crime flows

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you need to redefine `top` and `left` for the links as well as for the nodes:

```
pn.link.add(pv.Line)
   .left(function() pixels[this.index].x)
   .top(function() pixels[this.index].y);

pn.node.add(pv.Dot)
   .left(function() pixels[this.index].x)
   .top(function() pixels[this.index].y);
```

...though I'm not sure that `pixels[this.index]` will work for the line - you might try this instead:

```
pn.link.add(pv.Line)
   .left(function(d) pixels[d.index].x)
   .top(function(d) pixels[d.index].y);

pn.node.add(pv.Dot)
   .left(function(d) pixels[d.index].x)
   .top(function(d) pixels[d.index].y);
```

or, if you wanted to be a little more concise:

```
var x = function(d) pixels[d.index].x,
    y = function(d) pixels[d.index].y;

pn.link.add(pv.Line)
   .left(x)
   .top(y);

pn.node.add(pv.Dot)
   .left(x)
   .top(y);
```

In any case, as you can see, the issue is that the `link` mark expects, by default, that the data has a particular format (`{ x: <x-value>, y: <y-value>}`), just as the `node` mark does, and you need to tell it that your data is set up differently.

I put together a simple fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/NY7G3/ - it doesn't use the map, and just interprets the lat/lon as pixel values, but might be helpful as a proof of concept.